# d3.js v4 nest to hierarchy - Unable to read value

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I am having a little bit of trouble with the below function.

I pass a d3 nest to this function and convert it to a d3 hierarchy.

Would like to size my circles (in a pack) as per scaledFTE. However, I am unable to refer to the scaledFTE value.

I attach the console screenshot showing the D3hierarchy and the error message.

Thanks for your help

```
function layoutAndRenderHierarchyInNestFormat (nestFormatHierarchy, rootName){
    //Lays out and renders hierarchy in "nest" ("key-values" format).
    
        //Move the 'nest' array into a root node:
        var datasetAsJsonD3Hierarchy = {"key":rootName, "values": nestFormatHierarchy}
        
        console.log(datasetAsJsonD3Hierarchy)

        //Now create hierarchy structure 
        //Note that we need to add the "children" accessor "d=>d.values" in order
        //to tell d3.hierarchy to use nest's 'values' as children
        hierarchyGraph = d3
            .hierarchy(datasetAsJsonD3Hierarchy, d=>d.values) 
            //NB below is required for d3.pack etc that use a size attribute (e.g. for the different sizes of circles in d3.pack)
            .sum(d=>d.value.scaledFTE) //accessor for size data (e.g. circle size in a d3.pack)
               
            console.log(hierarchyGraph)
        
        //Can now calculate position data and render
        calculatepositionsAndRender(hierarchyGraph);
    }


[Screenshot of raw data structure][1]
[Console screenshot showing nest/hierarchy data structure][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5yXst.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZ60A.png
```

Comment: Try .sum(d => d.scaledFTE)

Comment: Thank you. I tried that already but for some reason it ends up giving me a Nan for r value.

Comment: you are right - I misread from your picture. Can you post your data- its really hard to help otherwise. It seems not every node contains the property value. Does the root contain the property value?

Comment: Thanks. The raw data is quite big.  All the entries have a scaledFTE value. I first make them a nest and the nest is passed on to the d3.hierarchy. `    nest_pack = d3.nest()
    .key(e=>e['Main panel'])
    .key(e=>e.UoAString) 
    .rollup(function(leaves) { return {"scaledFTE": d3.sum(leaves, d=>d.context.scaledFTE)}})
    //.rollup(e=>e.context.scaledFTE)
    .entries(dataModel.refEntries)
 


 pc1 = pack("#packDiv")  
   .loadAndRenderNestDataset(nest_pack, "REF2014") `

Comment: Each data entry looks like the screenshot posted in the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some nodes of your nested data do not contain d.value (e.g. in your screenshot the node with the key: *"REF2014"*).

```
d3.hierarchy(...).sum(accessor function) // iterates over every node and calls the accessor function. So nodes with no value property lead to an error when calling .sum(d=>d.value.scaledFTE).
```

> see also https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#node_sum

So you might do this:

```
function layoutAndRenderHierarchyInNestFormat (nestFormatHierarchy, rootName){
//Lays out and renders hierarchy in "nest" ("key-values" format).

    //Move the 'nest' array into a root node:
    var datasetAsJsonD3Hierarchy = {"key":rootName, "values": nestFormatHierarchy}
    
    console.log(datasetAsJsonD3Hierarchy)

    //Now create hierarchy structure 
    //Note that we need to add the "children" accessor "d=>d.values" in order
    //to tell d3.hierarchy to use nest's 'values' as children
    hierarchyGraph = d3
        .hierarchy(datasetAsJsonD3Hierarchy, d=>d.values) 
        //NB below is required for d3.pack etc that use a size attribute (e.g. for the different sizes of circles in d3.pack)
        .sum(d=> d.value ? d.value.scaledFTE : 0) //accessor for size data (e.g. circle size in a d3.pack)
           
        console.log(hierarchyGraph)
    
    //Can now calculate position data and render
    calculatepositionsAndRender(hierarchyGraph);
}
```

Comment: Great. That was the issue. I did a nest rollup and only the lowest level nodes have "value". Thanks a lot for pointing this out

Comment: I am glad it helped! you can accept my answer then